# Contacts are listing in one row of listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I make an app in which phone contact show in listview. but i want to convert it into widget. ie, I want to show contact list on the homescreen in a listview. I searched on google and found some example but none worked. any one has any link. I am not posting my code because it not worked. any help will be appriciated

## Update :-

I am able to show list on homescreen. **how to bind this listview to contact list**
I tried to add this method in my viewfactory class

```
public void getnumber(ContentResolver cr) {
        Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phone.moveToNext()) {
            Info info = new Info();
            ids = phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
            info.phone=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            info.name=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            info.picture=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
            System.out.println("...........name");

            aa.add(new ContactStock(info.name,info.phone));
        }
        phone.close();
        //Collections.sort(aa);
        adapt=new ContactListAdapter(MainActivity.this, aa);
        //listcontact.setAdapter(new ContactListAdapter(MainActivity.this, aa));
        //adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Info>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listcontact.setAdapter(adapt);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, it is working in my app but not in homescreen widget

## Update 2 :-

I am showing contact list in widget but all contacts are showing in one row.My remote view class is

```
public class DialerViewFactory implements RemoteViewsFactory {

private static final int mCount = 2;
private List<Info> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<Info>();
private Context mContext;
private int mAppWidgetId;
public DialerViewFactory(Context context,Intent intent){
    mContext=context;
    mAppWidgetId=intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mCount;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //ContentResolver cr=mContext.getContentResolver();
    //getnumber(cr);
    RemoteViews rv=new RemoteViews(mContext.getPackageName(),R.layout.row);
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textrow1, mWidgetItems.toString());
    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textrow2, "Kya");
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt(DialerWidgetProvider.EXTRA_ITEM, position);
    Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
    fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
    rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.textrow1, fillInIntent);
    return rv;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentResolver cr1=mContext.getContentResolver();
    getnumber(cr1);
}

@Override
public void onDataSetChanged() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void getnumber(ContentResolver cr) {
    Cursor phone = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while (phone.moveToNext()) {
        Info info = new Info();
        info.phone=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        info.name=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        info.picture=phone.getString(phone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI));
        System.out.println("...........name");
        mWidgetItems.add(info);
    }
    phone.close();
}
class Info {
  public String name;
  public String phone;
  public String picture;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  } 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [AppWidgets using Collections](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#collections). This can accept a `ListView` as the widget for presenting your data.

This will basically consist of

- an [AppWidgetProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html), as in any widget
- a [RemoteViewsService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.html) / [RemoteViewsFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory.html), responsible for
  producing the views in your ListView, much like an Adapter would do.

Since you are not sharing your code, it's hard to say what is not working for you, but you can find working examples in the sdk samples. Note that the samples have apparently been removed from latest sdk versions, so you should probably download the samples for older sdk's, if I remember correctly. You can also browse the source [here](http://docs.huihoo.com/android/3.0/resources/samples/StackWidget/).

**EDIT** :

```
adapt=new ContactListAdapter(MainActivity.this, aa);
listcontact.setAdapter(adapt);
```

This will not work in app-widgets, for 2 reasons :

- You don't have an Activity available. For widgets, you can use the Context provided as argument of the `onUpdate` callback in your `AppWidgetProvider`, although in your case it probably won't be needed.
- You don't instantiate an `Adapter` for app-widgets. To bind data to your `ListView` on your homescreen, you call [setRemoteAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#setRemoteAdapter%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) on the main `RemoteView` inside your `AppWidgetProvider` (in the `onUpdate` method), like this :

Example :

```
// Setup the intent which points to the StackViewService which will
// provide the views for this collection.
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetService.class);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);

// When intents are compared, the extras are ignored, so we need to embed the extras
// into the data so that the extras will not be ignored.
intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));

// Creating the main RemoteView and binding data to it.
RemoteViews rv = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
rv.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.listview, intent);
```

Basically, the `RemoteViewsFactory's` `getViewAt` method acts much like the `getView` in an `Adapter` would, you just have to copy and adapt the code of your adapter to make it work in the `RemoteViewsFactory`. The sample of StackWidget contains a `RemoteViewsFactory` where all the method are commented to let you know where to perform which tasks.

**EDIT 2 :**

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // This method tells the factory how many rows it has to produce
    // you should be returning the size of your data collection
    // so in your case :
    return mWidgetItems.size();
}
```

Also, in you `getViewAt` method you are setting the text as the `toString()` of the array (this is why you have all contacts in one row), whereas you should read the fields of the individual `Info` object for the position given by the method:

```
// get the current Info object by position :
Info currentInfo = mWidgetItems.get(position);
// then use that object to fill each row, like in getView for an Adapter, for example :
rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textrow1, currentInfo.phone);
rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textrow2, currentInfo.name);
```

Comment: thanks for sharing links, i worked on them and able to create listview on homescreen. but how to show contact list on homescreen. i tried some remoteview factory method but doesn't work.

Comment: Edited my answwer to show how to bind data to a ListView on the homescreen.

Comment: thanks for edit, my listview is showing all contact in one row in the form of array ?

Comment: Edited again ;) Not sure what you intend to do with the position in the fillInIntent, but if the widget is supposed to call the contact on click of a row, wouldn't it be better to pass the phone number directly ? Also, I'm not sure but I think it would be better to set an id for the parent layout of each ListView row and set the fillInIntent for that id, rather than on one particular TextView inside your row. I've never tested that so I might be wrong but setting it on the parent layout definitely works for me ;)

Comment: thanks you solved my prob, +1 + accept ans + bounty for you,can you tell me If i can add edittext in widget and perform search by typing in edittext i can easily do it in app. but if I add edittext to widget layout in listview is hide from homescreen and it shows problam loading widget. any link or tip how to do that if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty and glad you made it work ;) For the EditText on the home screen, I hate to be a bearer of bad news, but it looks like you can't do it, except if you target only HTC phones. You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868367/is-there-any-way-to-put-an-edittext-input-field-into-a-homescreen-widget for details (and maybe a work around ?). Not sure why that limitation exists, though, but it would be interesting to investigate ... If I find details on that, I'll post them here to let you know.

Comment: I read this issue about edittext somewhere. but not sure. but now i found some other way to do search in listview. thanks for helping me.